# Add attribute content-type with a link that corresponds to the button

Tags: javascript, jquery

What would be the best way to programmatically add the attribute content-type with a link that corresponds to the buttons? So for example, for the first button add attribute `content-type: link`, then for the second button add `content-type: link2` and so on.

JS

```
$('button').attr('content-type', 'link');
$('button').attr('content-type', 'link2');
$('button').attr('content-type', 'link3');
```

HTML - What the end result should look like:

```
<button content-type="link">First Button</button>
<button content-type="link2">Second Button</button>
<button content-type="link3">Third Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to using .each() fun like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").each(function(i))
   {
      if(i == 0)
      {
         $(this).attr("content-type","link");
      }
      else
      {
         $(this).attr("content-type","link"+(i+1));
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Cool, is there a way to strip out the 0 for the first button?